# Specific Language in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there any difference in between proving uniqueness of an identity element of a binary system and proving a binary system can have at most one identity element? If the binary system can't have more than one identity element, is it safe to say that the identity element is unique?

Comment: If a binary system can have at most one identity element, you still need to show there are not zero identity elements, ie, existence in the first place. But yes, two or more identity elements is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is the set of identity elements.

"There exists an identity" means "$|X|>0$".

"The identity is unique" means that if $x,y$ are identities, then $x=y$. In that case, clearly $|X|\leq 1$.

Then clearly when there exists one unique identity $|X|=1$.

"A binary operation has at most one identity" just says that $|X|\leq 1$, and leaves open the possibility that there is no identity at all.

So they are not, strictly speaking, the same thing.